# php chat client

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i need to create a chat application in php+js+ajax  which need to be integrated to a site, where am stuck is to create a chat window , that need to be constant while going through different pages in the site  . if any one can suggest a better way i will be grateful, thanks in advance

Comment: Only thing you can use iframe. Keep this iframe chat window in corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the chat window staying when you change pages, I can think of three options:

1. Put the chat in a separate frame and only change the main frame when going to a new page.
2. Change the page content with AJAX instead of making a full page reload.
3. Assuming the chat messages are being stored on the server, simply repopulate the chat with the most recent messages after the new page loads.

Answer (score 3):

As for the actual chat application...

Using some kind of technology to push data from the server -> your users is the best way to achieve a real-time chat application.

I would highly recommend checking out [APE (Ajax Push Engine)](http://www.ape-project.org/).

It takes care of the server-side stuff and allows you to seamlessly transfer data from the server -> client.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tutorials available, try one of these three that came up first from a Google search for "php chat tutorial":

- http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/PHP/Chat-Systems/1
- http://code.jenseng.com/jenChat/
- http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=9