# Resources For Making a Chat Using PHP

Tags: php, resources, chat

I'm going to develop a simple chat site to help my friend site, that needs a chat support feature and because I like to test my PHP knowledge, but first I'm needing some resources where I can start from. I want to start with something very very very simple, then I start to improve it(as I usually like to make things).

So can you share some resources that I will need to make this? Like examples, snippet and docs?

*PS: I'm not so good with Javascript neither AJAX*

Comment: You will need to get good with JavaScript or AJAX if you want the chat to be real-time. Otherwise users will probably have to POST the form everytime they want to send a message.

Comment: If you don't have JS abilities (AJAX is a subset of those) then you'll have *a lot* of difficulty getting something even closely resembling a live chat.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner More important than that, they will need to reload to get anyone's response! (They could also PUSH the form)

Comment: @cwallenpoole: at which point it's more of a forum that everyone is hitting "Refresh" on than an actual chat program.

Comment: Hmm, sorry my English is bad. I mean that I have some medium experience with Javascript(I never tried AJAX), not a advanced programmer.  Now everyone understood? **;)**

Comment: Please point out why none of the [answers to these existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chat+php) answer your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php chat client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055020/php-chat-client)

Answer (score 0):

Since you requested a *very very very* simple solution, here's a full-of-flaws-working-example.

regards,

//t

```
<?
//chat.php
//collect input from user
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  //submitted by form - add to conversation...
  //get conversation from file in server to array..
  if (!file_exists('conversation.txt'))
    file_put_contents('conversation.txt',serialize(array()));
  $a = unserialize(file_get_contents('conversation.txt'));
  //add the new entry to the conversation
  $a[] = array(
    'user' => $_POST['user'],
    'line' => $_POST['line']
  );
  //if conv. > 20 msg, crop
  if (sizeof($a)>20) $a = array_split($a, sizeof($a)-20);
  //now save..
  file_put_contents('conversation.txt',serialize($a)); 
  //and we're done with logic..
}
//from here, only presentation..
?>
<html>
<body>
...
<?php
//show conv...
$a = unserialize(file_get_contents('conversation.txt'));    
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($a);$i++) {
  echo $a[$i]['user'] . ':' . $a[$i]['line'] . '<br />';
}
?>
//build a form to submit line...
<form name="frm1" method="post" action="chat.php">
  <input type="text" name="user" />
  <input type="text" name="line" size="60" />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<!-- add js that reloads as long as no entry in line... !-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function getChat() {
  if (document.frm1.line.value.length == 0) {
    //alert('reloading');
    location.reload(true);
  }
}
//add a simple js-timer to fire every 8 sec.
setInterval('getChat()',8000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```